# ~/oradiag_root folder after zend server ce installation on Centos 5.*

Tags: centos, zend-server-ce

does anyone know why this folder: ~/oradiag_root appears under home - cd ~ in Centos after Zend CE installation and whether it can be removed and is it possible to stop that to be created?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like it some sort of legacy and can be removed however reboot might be required which will recreate it but will start from scratch thus making it smaller.